# Get file name without extension?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, filenames, filehandle

I'm new to C++ world, I stuck with a very trivial problem i.e. to get file name without extension.

I have `TCHAR` variable containing `sample.txt`, and need to extract only `sample`, I used `PathFindFileName` function it just return same value what I passed.

I tried googling for solution but still no luck?!

EDIT: I always get three letter file extension, I have added the following code,
but at the end I get something like `Montage (2)««þîþ` how do I avoid junk chars at the end?

```
TCHAR* FileHandler::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TCHAR* fileName)
{
    int fileLength = _tcslen(fileName) - 4;
    TCHAR* value1 = new TCHAR;
    _tcsncpy(value1, fileName, fileLength);
    return value1;
}
```

Comment: You should mark something as an answer, or clarify your question to get the answer you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how it's done.

```
#ifdef UNICODE //Test to see if we're using wchar_ts or not.
    typedef std::wstring StringType;
#else
    typedef std::string StringType;
#endif

StringType GetBaseFilename(const TCHAR *filename)
{
    StringType fName(filename);
    size_t pos = fName.rfind(T("."));
    if(pos == StringType::npos)  //No extension.
        return fName;

    if(pos == 0)    //. is at the front. Not an extension.
        return fName;

    return fName.substr(0, pos);
}
```

This returns a std::string or a std::wstring, as appropriate to the UNICODE setting. To get back to a TCHAR*, you need to use StringType::c_str(); This is a const pointer, so you can't modify it, and it is not valid after the string object that produced it is destroyed.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> StringType;` would be cleaner.

Comment: doesn't work well in case of something like `abc_1.0.0.tar.gz`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [PathRemoveExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to remove extension from filename.

To get only the file name (**with** extension), you may have first to use [PathStripPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), followed by `PathRemoveExtension`.

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution,

```
string fileName = "sample.txt";
size_t position = fileName.find(".");
string extractName = (string::npos == position)? fileName : fileName.substr(0, position);
```

Comment: what, if the file name is "sample.txt.bak"?

Comment: The 'right' way would be to look for the last . in the filename, however there's also the issue with hidden unix files that start with a dot (ex .gitignore, .hgignore)

Comment: I don't thing `TCHAR` has substr method!

Comment: @Stephan: Then you would have to check for the . backwards?

Comment: @Stephan, it will still extract `"sample"`, because it `find()` for the first `"."`.

Comment: @Prashant, you have to store TCHAR to an `std::string`. This is just one of the soln.

Comment: @Prashant: you probably don't have the value 'sample.txt' in TCHAR because TCHAR can only hold 1 character. Likely you have a pointer or an array of TCHARs.

Comment: so it would be better to use `rfind` instead ... and to use `basic_string<TCHAR>` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
TCHAR* FileHandler::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TCHAR* fileName)
{
    int fileLength = _tcslen(fileName) - 4;
    TCHAR* value1 = new TCHAR[fileLength+1];
    _tcsncpy(value1, fileName, fileLength);
    return value1;
}
```

Comment: You assume, that an extension is always 3 characters long. What about .docx, manifest, .html,...?

Comment: I just corrected original example, this is not an implementation i would want

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Assuming the file name is in a string.

```
string fileName = your file.

string newFileName;

for (int count = 0;
   fileName[count] != '.';
   count++)
{
  newFileName.push_back(fileName[count]);
}
```

This will count up the letters in your original file name and add them one by one to the new file name string.

There are several ways to do this, but this is one basic way to do it.